# Firebase 10.15.0 > Storage.Swift > Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I created a Swift iOS app all through XCode, and installed the Firebase SDK package (version 10.15.0). Everything in my own files looks good as there are no errors and firebase is only being used in this project to access a storage bucket. I doubt it is relevant, but the only usage of firebase in my own code looks as follows...

```
import SwiftUI
import PassKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage
. . . 

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
. . .

func downloadPass(completion: @escaping((Bool) -> () )) {
        self.storageRef.child("passes/Tutorial_\(self.cardID).pkpass").getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error Downloading Local Resource:" + error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
            else{
                do {
                    let canAddPass = PKAddPassesViewController.canAddPasses()
                    if (canAddPass){
                        print("Creating a Pass")
                        self.newPass = try PKPass.init(data: data!)
                        completion(true)
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Device Cannot Add Passes")
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print ("Unknown Error")
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, whenever I attempt to preview or run the app, I get the following error coming from the read-only file, `Storage.swift` (The full file path is F`irebase > FirebaseStorage > Sources > Storage`)
The code errors out on the following block...

```
  @objc(storage) open class func storage() -> Storage {
    return storage(app: FirebaseApp.app()!)
  }
```

With the following error message...

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

While I believe I could figure out a workaround to this under normal circumstances, as previously mentioned this is a read-only file. I cannot touch the code that is in there.

What could the solution be, as I am not finding much of anything in terms of troubleshooting documentation from Firebase, and googling has not led me anywhere close to a solution thus far

Comment: Have you initialised Firebase in your ```AppDelegate```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return storage(app: FirebaseApp.app()!) or self.newPass = try PKPass.init(data: data!) causes the issue because of force unwrapping. Make sure that values exist in these before trying to retrieve them. Try changing it for a "?: instead of a "!" for your PKPass.init(data: data!). If the error is still happening, your FirebaseApp is not correctly configured. Make sure it is configured in your AppDelegate:

```
 class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
     
     var appState: AppState?
     var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
 
     func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
         
         // Initial Firebase configuration
         FirebaseApp.configure() } }
```

Make sure that Firebase is properly configured in your Info.plist

Comment: Perfect, thank you!